# GDI SelectClipRgn become very slow when the region is much large than the screen

Tags: c++, gis, gdi

I have a GIS application that uses GDI to draw complex maps. Some of the complex polygons are used as clip regions by calling `SelectClipRgn`. Things work well when the clipping polygon is relatively small. However, when user zooms in, the polygon can become very large(hundreds of times larger than the screen), and the `SelectClipRgn` call takes several seconds.

I tried to call `SetViewPort` with screen rectangle before calling SelectClipRgn. Also, I tried to calculate the intersection of the clipping polygon and the screen rectangle.  The intersection calculation is expensive too.

Did I miss something when calling SelectClipRgn? Are there any better ways to get the clipping operation done?

PS: The clip region is used to Bitblt some pattern bitmaps on it.

Comment: When you use GDI, a clipping region is not needed to guard exceptions. However, a clipping region will help preventing ARC display errors. So it is good to use it. But when the clipping region becomes larger than your window is, just set the window itself as clipping region and leave it there. The edges of your clipping region are not important when the edges all reside outside your window. On zoomin, do the check and only set a new region when it is needed. When all edges are outside view, you can use a rectangle.

Comment: Even the clipping region is large, the polygon edge may still lies inside screen, so I can't use the rectangle as clip region.